# Why can't I hide my active application (e.g., Chrome)?

Tags: applications, google-chrome

This happens from time to time: the "hide" option is just grayed out and the usual shortcut doesn't work. I'm not doing anything special or stuck in a modal window—it just isn't available.

[image: hiding Chrome]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is OS X default behavior in every app if you have hidden all other apps before with "Hide Others" or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. In such a case it's not possible to hide the front most app, that's why both options are greyed out/inactive.

Comment: Wow, that is nuts. User-unfriendly. "You told me to do X before, and now I see you're telling me to do Y. Faced with contradicting [ed. not really] instructions, I'll just ignore this last thing you told me to do."

Comment: "it's not possible to hide the front most app". This is a weird assumption Mac OS makes. I believe some people want to access the desktop (without some gesture), or have a "clean" state of windows. The shortcut I found is to switch to the Finder and hit ⌥+⌘+H.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a workaround:

If you hold the <kbd>⌥</kbd>-key and click the desktop, your app will hide.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happened to me. I figured out that Google Chrome was in full screen mode on another (secondary) display. Consequently, OS X could not hide it.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Chrome to and select "Show All", the option will reappear.

Comment: Sure, "We're looking for long answers...", but this is the only answer describing how to fix the situation.

Comment: This happened to me with Chrome plus other Chrome-based apps such as WhatsApp web